# What's cheaper: subtraction or higher exponent?

Tags: java, optimization, cycle

I realize this is petty, but which calculation tends to be cheaper?

```
Math.pow(2,x); // exponent
Math.pow(2,x-1); // subtraction, then smaller exponent
```

I happen to be thinking of this in terms of a java application. (And I'm on openjdk version 1.8.0_121.)

Comment: The `Math.pow()` is probably going to be a hundred times more expensive than a subtraction that you'll be pretty hard-pressed just to make a benchmark to show a difference. At least not without targeting special cases like `Math.pow(x, 0)`.

Comment: Are you dealing with integers? Can you left shift?

Comment: `Math.pow` has special cases that make its performance non-smooth in the exponent. For example it's very fast if the exponent is 2, 1, or 0, and "kind of fast" for -1. Dropping out of those special cases with the -1 would be bad, but using the -1 to get into one of those cases is great.

Comment: Is `x` integer?

Comment: I believe compiler(people who made it) is smart enough to replace such pow with left shift himself(assuming x is integer), therefore i think upper will be faster because left shifting is much quicker than substraction

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, you are computing different values.

Comment: Yes. x is an integer.